# Inside HTML alt attribute I want to show copyright symbol as a Superscript

Tags: html, css, html-tag-details

I have an image and on an alt attribute. I want to show copyright symbol a Superscript.

```
<img src="img_flower.jpg" alt="flwer&copy; Logos"/>
```

currently it is showing like "flwer© Logos"

Comment: `alt` is an **attribute**, not a tag.

Comment: @Quentin there does not seem to be Unicode character "superscript copyright sign" , so for this particular question linked answer will most probably not help much.

Comment: @myf — That's as close as you are going to come. Alt attributes do not provide any mechanism for partial formatting.

Comment: @user1872177 headsup: standards- and accessibility-wise, copyright information does not belong to the alt attribute anyway. Such information should be included in the alt if and only if it is really (visibly) present in the image content.